# I have inputted a number but it gives me error

Tags: java

So i have these problem that it wont detect the value of jtextfield. Anybody can help me?

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at mypackage.temp_conv.ConvertActionPerformed(temp_conv.java:133)
at mypackage.temp_conv.access$000(temp_conv.java:12)
at mypackage.temp_conv$1.actionPerformed(temp_conv.java:47)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)

And this is my code.

```
private void ConvertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    double celsius = Integer.parseInt(cfield.getText());
    double fahren = Integer.parseInt(ffield.getText());
    if(celsius >= 0){
    total = (9/5) * celsius + 32;
    ffield.setText("" + total);
    }
    else if(fahren >= 0){
    total = (5/9) * fahren - 32;
    ffield.setText("" + total);
    }
    cfield.setEditable(false);
    ffield.setEditable(false);

}                                       

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    cfield.setText("");
    ffield.setText("");
    cfield.setEditable(true);
    ffield.setEditable(true);

}
```

Comment: Either `cfield.getText()` or `ffield.getText()` is returning an empty field.

Comment: so what do i need to do?

Comment: because supposed to be when i enter a value and press convert button it should compute the celsius either fahrenheit right?

Comment: Debug to see why the fields are returning an empty `String`

Comment: and i dont know how to debug as well im beginner tho

Comment: You‘re asking what your program is supposed to do? In your code you’re parsing the value of both input fields to Integer. From your comment it reads like you only want to parse the one where a user entered a value.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Uhm sorry i alread fixed it. Thanks alot guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    double celsius = Double.valueOf(cfield.getText());
    double fahren = Double.valueOf(ffield.getText());
    // do calculations

} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    // report the error with a logger
    // or fix the error
    // or escape out 
}
```

Comment: A good start, but a better solution would be: don't just fetch text field content and make comparisons. First **validate** if the field contains valid content. If yes, compute results. Otherwise: tell the user to fix his input.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here when you try to parse the string to a number.

```
    double celsius = Integer.parseInt(cfield.getText());
    double fahren = Integer.parseInt(ffield.getText());
```

You are not checking whether the text in the textfield can be parsed in to a number or not. So when an empty string is taken for parsing a NumberFormatException is raised. You should use exception handling to deal with this situation or manually check before parsing of which the former is the right choice.

```
try
{
    double celsius = Integer.parseInt(cfield.getText());
    double fahren = Integer.parseInt(ffield.getText());
}catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Always try to use exception handling on code that might raise an exception.